# Trying to extract obfuscated zip archive that is part of a multi-disk archive

Tags: ubuntu, zip, obfuscation, archive, deobfuscation

I am trying to extract the contents of an obfuscated zip archive. I believe that the issue is that there is no signature indicating the end of the archive:

`$ hexdump`

```
00000000  50 4b 03 04 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |PK..............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 89 50  |...............P|
00000020  4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00  00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00  |NG........IHDR..|
00000030  00 a3 00 00 00 0d 08 03  00 00 00 f2 a4 2e 2c 00  |..............,.|
00000040  00 00 06 50 4c 54 45 00  00 00 c4 c4 c4 00 5e 93  |...PLTE.......^.|
00000050  b0 00 00 00 02 74 52 4e  53 18 4f 12 eb 09 60 00  |.....tRNS.O...`.|
00000060  00 00 78 49                                       |..xI|
00000064
```

I also know that this archive can be extracted by some app-specific tools, however programs like `unzip` and `7z` have trouble. `unzip` can read the file paths/names, but extracts all 0 byte files, and `7z` simply cannot read it.

`$ zipinfo`

```
Archive:  myzip.zip
Zip file size: 34714819 bytes, number of entries: 0

   [myzip.zip]:
     Zipfile is disk 65535 of a multi-disk archive, and this is not the disk on
     which the central zipfile directory begins (disk 0).
```

`zipinfo` states that this is a "multi-disk archive", however I have not been able to find any results that detail what this is, or how to deal with it.

Any ideas on how I could proceed?

Comment: Why do you think there is a data to extract from it?  It looks simply broken.

Comment: Because this zip can be extracted by the unarchivers of certain games, and is specifically designed to be protected against people while still working with intended programs.

Comment: Zip obfuscation is real, and targeting the loose specification makes it easy to create archives that can only be read in a specific way. I have plenty of samples on a project of mine demonstrating this - https://github.com/Col-E/LL-Java-Zip/blob/master/src/test/java/software/coley/lljzip/ZipComparisonShowcaseTest.java

You can use it in a Java project to see if one of the provided parse strategies reads from your file.